# How to generate a SQL query to for this data?

Tags: sql-server, intervals

I have a SQL Server 2005 table in which I store the book exchanges that take place between two students.

```
ExchangeID   BookID   ExchangeDate   FromPersName   ToPersName
1            23       23.12.2011     John           Matt
2            22       15.02.2012     Billy          Ken
3            23       27.12.2011     Matt           Riddley
5            23       05.03.2012     Riddley        Josh
6            22       08.03.2012     Ken            Rachel
7            23       19.03.2012     Josh           Laura
8            23       15.01.2013     Laura          Mike
9            22       17.01.2013     Rachel         Stephanie
```

I want to generate a report for a specified year that looks like this:

```
Year:2012

BookID    PersonName      ReceivingDate   DeliveryDate
23        Matt            01.01.2012      27.02.2012
23        Riddley         27.02.2012      05.03.2012
23        Josh            05.03.2012      19.03.2012
23        Laura           19.03.2012      31.12.2012
22        Ken             01.01.2012      08.03.2012
22        Rachel          08.03.2012      31.12.2012
```

Comment: Homework? I Hope so - the moment you get 2 students with the same name you are dead. I suggest a separate table (like books) for people.

Comment: Did you try anything? does it need to be efficient, if so, what indexes do you have on that table?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I don't know where to begin.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is half solution.You need to change it a litle bit to work. I will not make whole query for Your homework. Put some effort!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39d73/17

Comment: I can't figure out the other part. I've added a ISNULL to the ReceivingDate. I've been trying to modify the CASE WHEN ELSE END statement, but to no avail. If a person receives it and gives it away in a different year (let's say 2011) than the one I'm generating the report for (2012), then the query doesn't return the corret data. Please help! PS: This is not a homework assignment.

Comment: Well, if you are trying to check for 2011, then you need some data in the table to get some in your query. Coz the query will fail if there is none. On other part, with case/when/else/end. You can do case on whole subquery. I have added you a where part so it does select only exchanges with date <01.01.2013   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39d73/21

Comment: If we are running the report for 2012 and a person receives a book and gives it away in 2011 or earlier (the case with Steven and John) then the query shouldn't include those persons. Same with a person receives a book and gives it away in 2013 or later. See [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bf33/1)

Answer (score 0):

table can join it self

```
select ex1.BookID,ex1.toPersName,ex1.ExchangeDate as DeliveryDate,Exchanges.ExchangeDate    
as ReceivingDate from Exchanges as ex1 inner join Exchanges on      
ex1.toPersName=Exchanges.FromPersName
```